# Can degree of root field exceed the number of roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm doing a self study in Abstract Algebra, and have a question that seems like it should be very easy.  (Perhaps, I'm just in overload.)

Can the degree of a root field of a polynomial exceed the number of roots?

More formally:
Let a(x) be any polynomial in F[x], where F is a field, and let F(c1,c2,...,cn) be the root field of a(x).  Then can [F(c1,c2,...,cn]:F] exceed the number of roots of a(x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly! Take $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and let $f=t^3-2$, for instance. If $\zeta=e^{2\pi i /3}$, then $f$ has roots $2^{1/3}, \zeta 2^{1/3}, \zeta^2 2^{1/3}$, so the root field of $f$ over $F$ is $F(\zeta, 2^{1/3})$. Now $F(2^{1/3})$ is contained in this root field and is a degree three extension over $F$ since the polynomial $t^3-2$ is irreducible over $F$ (by Eisenstein, say), but $F(2^{1/3})$ cannot be the whole root field since it's contained in $\mathbb{R}$! Thus the degree of the root field over the base field has to be strictly greater than three.

It's not hard to see that the degree of the extension is actually 6.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume $p(X)\in F[X]$ is irreducible.

The degree of the splitting field of $p$ over $F$ is *at least* n, and is at most $n$-factorial. In fact, it's much more likely to be $n!$ than not as $n$ grows large.

If the splitting field of $p(X)$ has degree $n$, $p(X)$ is called a *normal* polynomial. These are quite exceptional, with the property that $F(\alpha)$ is Galois over $F$, for any root $\alpha$ of $p(X)$.